# How do I set the record straight?

Tags: interviewing, job-search, job-offer, employment-gaps

I have been interviewing with companies but it seems like they already know that I am currently not employed. I have lied at those interviews that I was employed when I am currently not. I finished with my last employer a month ago. 
There are a couple of companies that are interested in me and I don't want them to look at other candidates just because of the fact that I lied as I like both roles and I did well at  the interviews. 
How do I set the record straight by letting them know that I am currently not employed but was employed when I applied for the job? Should I even do that, or am I just being paranoid that they think I do not have integrity?

Comment: What's wrong with saying "I am currently unemployed."?

Comment: If you were employed when you applied, then you did not lie. I don't understand your description.

Comment: I went for an interview after I had finished with my old employer. When asked if I was still with my old employer, I said "yes" when I should have said "no". Is that clearer?

Answer (score 11):

The damage has already been done, so leave it alone, you can only make it worse.

Chances are they don't know so why draw attention to the fact.

And stop telling lies.

Comment: I agree although there is a high degree of chances of them already knowing. Are they just waiting for me to come clean? If I tell them, will I be left with no skin in the game and therefore will lose negotiation power around pay & benefits?

Comment: They're not waiting for you to come clean, if I knew someone was lying their application goes straight in the bin. So either they don't know, don't care, or you have already missed out. Either way nothing you can do will help.

Comment: Companies don't wait for liars to come clean.  If they're candidates, what Kilisi does is typical.  If they're employees, they get fired.  If it is law-breaking, cops and lawyers get called.  Companies have no reason to save your butt.